# Keccak-f Round constants Hex to binary is not a single bit

Tags: javascript, security, binary, hex, keccak

I'm implementing the Keccak-f ι step using javascript, the formula is as follow:

```
 # ι step
  A[0,0] = A[0,0] xor RC
```

RC is an array of round constants in Hex and A[0,0] is a single bit in Binary

The problem occurs on the following line

```
A[0,0] = 0, RC = 0x0000000000008082
```

when I convert RC to Binary using the code:

```
let temp = (parseInt(RC, 16).toString(2)).padStart(8, '0');//110010100010011000
A[0][0] = A[0][0] ^ temp; //16975297
```

the result is not a single bit, rather is a large number 16975297, but I need a single bit.

I tried to convert the large number 16975297 to binary but it is not a single bit as well.
I need some help, thank you!

Comment: If A[0,0] is just zero, and you're XOR'ing that with RC then the output will just be RC. As 0 ^ Z always equals Z.

Comment: Hi Matt, but if I have done correctly, the result should only be one bit